# MudTable Multi Select only what is displayed

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have created a MudTable with MultiSelection. The problem I now have is that when I use the "SelectAll" it will select every row from the table (as expected).

Is there a way to only select the rows which are shown, as you are able to change the "rows per page". So if Rows per page is 25, the select all will only select 25 rows.

( Code from the MultiSelection table can be found on https://mudblazor.com/components/table#multi-selection )

Comment: It partly does. The solution given there have some minor bugs, but these are fixable.

Comment: If there are bugs then you can comment about them under the answer so it can be improved.